# Windows crashes whenever I run pip -V in the CMD

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, crash

Whenever I run pip -V in the cmd my windows computer gets the blue frowny face appears.

I have previously run the python command and see that it is installed. Also, during set up of python 3.7 I installed pip. So naturally i uninstalled it and installed pip again using the script.

Comment: any error-logs? windows/pip/python version, etc..? (Win10 x64, py3.5, pip19.0.1 works fine with `pip -V`)

Answer (score 0):

You say that python is in good shape, yet pip is not.
Ok.

Simply run this [synonym](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
python -m pip -V
```

You may want to track down where the pip & python commands are coming from,
and how they managed to get out of sync.
From a cygwin bash prompt you can certainly do `$ which pip`.
On some win10 hosts you may be able to do `C:\> where pip`.
From Power Shell, `PS\> Get-Command pip` should display what you need to know.